# Hide Element in Shiny RMarkdown

Tags: shiny, r-markdown, show-hide, reactive

I was wondering wether it was possible to hide a element in shiny rmarkdown from the user and still get the reactive value.

````
---
title: "My Title"
author: "My Name"
date: "Today"
output:
  rmdformats::html_clean:
  highlight: kate
runtime: shiny
---

```{r knitr_init, echo=FALSE, cache=FALSE}
library(knitr)
library(rmdformats)

## Global options
options(max.print="75")
opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE,
               cache=TRUE,
               prompt=FALSE,
               tidy=TRUE,
               comment=NA,
               message=FALSE,
               warning=FALSE)
opts_knit$set(width=75)
```

```{r setup, include=FALSE}

library(tidyverse)
library(shinyjs)
```

```{r name, echo=FALSE, cache=FALSE}

inputPanel(   
  selectizeInput(inputId = "Name", label = "Choose Name", choices=c("Rachel","Mike"), selected="Mike"),
   numericInput(inputId = "Cluster", label = "Choose Cluster", min = 1, max=10, value = 1 ,step = 1)

)

renderText(paste("Hallo:",input$Cluster))      
```
````

What I got is this rmarkdown: [Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmE6J.png)

See Hallo: 1, what shows, that renderText get the reactive value from input$Cluster. Is it possible to somehow hide this numericInput, that it looks like this: [Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYDvF.png)

I've tried shinyjs with different settings but it was no good.

Answer (score 0):

At least two options here:

**1. Use plain CSS**

```
<style>
#Cluster {
  display :none;
}
</style>
```

This way you will have to delete the label for the `numericInput`.

**2. Use jQuery to select the parent div containing label and input field**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#Cluster').parent('div').css('display', 'none');
});
</script>
```

Here we just hide the whole container.

Put either of those right underneath your YAML header.